# how can I execute command through ssh, remote is windows

Tags: bash, shell-script, shell, ssh, windows

My remote machine is a windows and I am doing `ssh` from ubuntu to windows.

I want to use git bash instead of command prompt, but running the `ssh` will bring me to the default command prompt, is there any way that I could invoke git bash through `ssh`?

I try the following command not working:

```
ssh Administrator@54.xxx.xxx.207 < "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe"
```

I can run the following command to after ssh to start the git bash, but I am seeking a way to automate this process?

```
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login
```

I am using Windows 2012 R2

Comment: You should specify the version of Windows you're using on your server. Since Windows 10, you can easily install bash and most certainly openssl along a Linux SSH server. On older systems, you may have to install Cygwin to make it possible to run SSH in a bash shell.

Comment: I am using Windows 2012 R2

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Yes, you can if you have [OpenSSH For Windows Server 2019 and Windows 10](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_install_firstuse) installed.

From [OpenSSH Server Configuration for Windows 10 1809 and Server 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/openssh/openssh_server_configuration):

> Configuring the default ssh shell is done in the Windows registry by adding the full path to the shell executable to `Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH` in the string value `DefaultShell`.
>
> As an example, the following Powershell command sets the default shell to be PowerShell.exe:
>
> ```
> New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Windows\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
> ```

To set Git Bash as default shell, run this snippet as administrator in the PowerShell:

```
New-ItemProperty -Path "HKLM:\SOFTWARE\OpenSSH" -Name DefaultShell -Value "C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" -PropertyType String -Force
```

To get a login shell, you could create a batch file `sh.bat` in `C:\Program Files\Git\bin` with this content:

```
@echo off
"C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.exe" --login
```

and replace the `DefaultShell` value with `C:\Program Files\Git\bin\sh.bat`.

The `DefaultShell` registry key is a new key, you can delete it to restore the default command prompt.

Comment: thank you, this works for me